# How to organaze tables in database

Tags: excel, database, database-design

I have to create a database for storing some information from two excel sheets.

Columns of the first sheet:

- *TS id*
- *City*
- *District*
- *Street*
- *Type of transformer station (RMU, PUTS)*
- **PDC**
- *Cabel length*

Columns of the second sheet:

- *TS id*
- *City*
- *District*
- *Street*
- *Type of transformer station (Reklozer, Sekcionalizer)*
- **TS Type**
- **Voltage**
- **Configuration**
- *Cabel length*

Depending on the type of the transformer station (RMU, PUTS or Reklozer, Sekcionalizer) each table has additional columns (PDC or TS Type, Voltage, Configuration).

I have thought of three possible solutions:

1. Make one table with all possible columns and insert nulls if the type of transformert station doesn't have such attribute. (Table will be too generic?)
2. Make two tables with the same columns as in sheets. (Duplication of columns?)
3. Make three tables. First contains common information for both sheets. Second and third reference first table and contain additional columns. (Too complicated scheme?)

What is the best way to map these excel sheets to database tables?

Comment: IMO this question is primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center. But you have 5 fields in common in both tables, the only difference would be Depending on the type of the transformer station (RMU, PUTS or Reklozer, Sekcionalizer). I don't know what you pretend to do in the future, but I would do your option #1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case I would vote for option 1. It's very simple and we are talking about 1-3 nullable columns, which is no big deal.

The proper way is option 3, though. It would be suitable if you had 10 station types resulting in some 30 nullable columns.